# How do I test that a specific exception is thrown in node.js and tap

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, tap

I use `assert(...)` on methods to validate arguments, e.g.

```
var assert = require('assert')

function someFunction(a, b, c) {
  assert(a, 'a required')
  assert(b, 'b required')
  assert(c, 'c required')
}
```

I am using [tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tap) and would like to write a test to validate that an *assert exception* was thrown. I cannot just test that another error is thrown, because the assert is essentially an early-guard. The bad input will eventually throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

You compare against an `assert.AssertionError` in your `t.throws()` e.g.

```
var test = require('tap').test

test('calling someFunction without arguments', function(t){
  t.throws(function(){
    someFunction()
  }, new assert.AssertionError({
    message: 'a required'
  }), 'throws assert error')
  t.end()
})
```

The `AssertionError` takes an object in it's constructor whose `.message` property will be compared against the thrown exception.